# creating conda environments from python.org installation

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda

I installed python 3.8 on my windows 10 laptop from python.org and would like to create conda environments with different python versions ( 3.6 ).

How would I do this?

BR

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+different+Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```

Comment: does that version have to be already installed on my laptop or will it automatically download it for me?

Comment: It will automatically download the requirements for you. It will prompt you though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. is it possible to use install pip and conda together? I currently use pip to install packages as recommended for python.org installs. how do I then install conda as I don't see a pip install package for it. Not sure how they work hand in hand...Or is there a virtualenv option for the above?